# How to pass a dynamic template reference variable in a function using angular 6

Tags: angular

I am trying to achieve this functionality but getting error

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
    <div #menu{{i}}>
        //Some code
    </div>
    <div (onClick)="Clicked($event,menu{{i}})">
        //Some other code
    </div>
```

> Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 19 in [Clicked($event,menu{{i}})]

Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: Tried (onClick)="Clicked($event,menu+i) and (onClick)="Clicked($event,'menu'+i) still no luck

Comment: @KeshanNageswaran tried this didn't work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `ViewChildren` decorator which returns a `QueryList` : you don't need to use an index anymore, Angular will handle all of that for you.

See this [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbc8fy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to see it in action (open your console before clicking on the buttons)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem and solved it by referencing the unique id of the same element that I had the template reference variable on, and I believe you could do the same.

```
<div class="outer-element" #outerElement>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
    <div id="menu{{i}}">
        //Some code
    </div>
    <div (onClick)="Clicked($event, outerElement.querySelector('#menu' + i)">
        //Some other code
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Dynamic Template Reference is not feasible in Angular. You can try these 2 solutions.

Solution 1 :

Attach 'id' property to div element i.e 'menu1' and pass the id to the component on click method and access the DOM using document.querySelector()

Solution 2:

Create a attribute directive in which you can pass id as @Input and access elementRef in the constructor().